# $_SESSION not forwarding variable correctly

Tags: php, sql, session, variables

user query database and certain table fields must be stored and used in other pages.

in page 1 where the querytook place and prescription field is save in variable $_SESSION:

```
$query = " 
    SELECT 
        id, 
        full_name,
        address,
        email,
        telephone,
        prescription
    FROM patients 
    WHERE id 
    LIKE '%" . $patient_id . "%'";

    $PRESCRIPTION = 'prescription';


    $_SESSION['memory1'] = $PRESCRIPTION;
```

in page 2 where variable need reusing, am using this: `<?php echo "Our patient's prescription is: ".$_SESSION['memory1'];?></b>`

problem is that in page one I re used variable like this:`<?php echo htmlentities ($row[$PRESCRIPTION], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>` and it outputs the actual field result correctly. But on page 2 it is 'literally' displaying the characters prescription rather than it's stored content. it's liek in page 2 'prescription' has lost it's meaning.

I'm editing the question to confirm that I am using`<?php echo "Our patient's prescription is: ".$_SESSION['memory1'];?>` this code in page 2. therefore am referring to the stored variable.

With regards to the post that replied that I'm being too literal in page 1, then how come it's echoing ok in page one when used $PRESCRIPTION variable? if the literal is stored. in page 1 I would also get the prob of page 2 which returns the word prescription. BUT no, in page 1 I get the actual table field data that I require. in page 2 I just get the prescription word.

One last thing, I'm not using session_start, but am instead using ($_SESSION['user']) at start of every doc as I use a require("common.php"); that specifies conn etc.

hope this clarifies further.

thanks, waiting for your opinions

Comment: Are you doing session_start(); on every single file you use? At the top of the file?

Comment: Are you trying to use the variable `$PRESCRIPTION` on the second page instead of `$_SESSION['memory1']`? Sorry if I'm wrong, your question is just a bit unclear.

Comment: Would be helpful if you could post the full code for the first and second pages.

Comment: It's because you're saving the literal word 'prescription' in it, You should store the value you've got from your query in order for this to work

Comment: Yeah, it does look like that. In fact, I'm really confused by what you're doing! :P

Comment: If you are expecting the value on page 2 to show up with HTML-encoding, then you need to save the encoded version into session.  From what you have shown, you are not doing that.

Comment: You are putting it = to litterial prescription here:
$PRESCRIPTION = 'prescription';

Comment: How do I save the encoded version of my variable into $_SESSION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but I think what you want is:

Page 1:

```
//Query goes here...

session_start();
$_SESSION['memory1'] = $row[$PRESCRIPTION];  //Store original value in session
echo htmlentities($row[$PRESCRIPTION], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');  //Display value
```

Page 2:

```
session_start();
echo htmlentities($_SESSION['memory1'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');  //Display value
```

The important thing is that you do not store the encoded version of the string in the session, you just re-encode the value when you display it on the 2nd page.

Comment: you R frickin AWESOME! thanks man, one imp thing I had to do also is to save variable after it is displayed.. therefore after echoing it on page 1.. then comes the code $_SESSION[

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure that you have

```
session_start();
```

at the top of every single file to make sure that you maintain the session.